# About UIRefreshControl How to change the default pull down arrow in IOS6.0

Tags: ios6, uirefreshcontrol

```
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];//this just only change it color
```

Can I change the drop-down Arrow to some picture or another shape? How?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  You can only change the color of the arrow, but not the arrow itself.  If you would like to be able to do so, please [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) and it'll be considered.

Of course, you're also able to write one yourself, or use an open source variant.

Comment: yeah ,thank u ....some open source is easy to use and it's support right,left,up,down drag，thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hidden API version (in my actual code, maskImage is a category on UIImage).  I don't know if Apple will reject this.

```
static UIImage *maskImage(UIImage *image, UIColor *color) {
    UIImage *retval;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    [color set];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1];//
    retval = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return retval;
}

@protocol UIRefreshHacking <NSObject>
-(UIImageView*)arrow;
@end

@interface UIRefreshControl (GetAtContentView)
-(UIView<UIRefreshHacking>*)_contentView;
@end

@implementation UIRefreshControl (ChangeArrowColor)
-(BOOL)setArrowColor:(UIColor *)arrowColor {
    if(![self respondsToSelector:@selector(_contentView)]) {
        return NO;
    }
    UIView<UIRefreshHacking> *cv = [self _contentView];
    if(![cv respondsToSelector:@selector(arrow)]) {
        return NO;
    }
    UIImageView *iv = [cv arrow];
    iv.image = maskImage(iv.image, arrowColor);
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: This makes unicorns and kitties weep tears of blood. **PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE**. It relies on *implementation details* of `UIRefreshControl` that can change at any point in the future.  The only thing that is guaranteed is that the *API* will be consistent.

Comment: It won't crash.  The worst that happens is Apple changes something and your arrow is the wrong color - and chances are, they'll have an API to do it by then.

Comment: You will quite possibly be rejected for the `UIRefreshControl` category to get at the `_contentView` method.

Comment: It's simple enough to code around if they aren't doing runtime checks.  That's the beauty of a dynamic programming language.  My opinion is that you can either 1. use Apple's APIs and hack around their shortcomings or 2. reinvent the wheel and add code that isn't easily compatible with enhancements they'll add later.  Each is a valid option for what your end-goal and priorities are, but I'd prefer to remove a few lines of hack code rather than refactor my list views later when the latest greatest UITableViewController comes around.

Comment: If you think they're shortcomings, then surely you've [filed an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) to request they be addressed.  What's the bug number? I'd like track it's progress. You are, of course, welcome to do whatever you want in your code. But I wrote `UIRefreshControl`, and I personally don't like seeing my code abused like this. :)

Comment: Just from experience, I find that not doing things with the official APIs can end up being painful.  That means sometimes doing not so desirable things.  Like abusing your code. :)  I don't file many enhancement requests because they're usually not that important to me.  We aren't even using UIRefreshControl at work, for philosophical reasons, so it's out of my hands there.  So this is purely a recreational endeavor.

I would love to have a discussion with you about UIRefreshControl's philosophy, though, with regards to API decisions.